# Do extra parentheses have an impact on performance?

Tags: c

I have a program in C, that uses lots of mathematical calculations, At some places during calculation the expression has many redundant parenthesis and braces

```
eg: ((x*y)+(((z*c))))
```

Does It degrade the performance ? Should we avoid it?

Comment: Though it may degrade *just a little bit* your compilation time.

Comment: I thought it might be overhead to verify the correctness of parenthesis

Comment: However, needless parens, as you have here, don't do much in the way of making it easy to read,

Comment: The only reason you should avoid doing that is that it then looks like Lisp gone wrong mixed in your C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this shouldn't affect execution time since the expression will be simplified by the compiler.

It might have a minute effect on compilation time but note that word "minute" - it's doubtful you'd even notice.

Far more of an effect would be any developer reading that code. The superfluous parentheses may make it harder to understand or it may delay them a little while they curse the coder that inflicted such rubbish on them :-)

Comment: Not only will the expression be simplified by the compiler, parentheses simply just don't exist after the parsing phase and once the parse tree is built.

Comment: Well, @Cornstalks, you're presupposing the way the compiler works. While you're probably right (within 0.00000001%), we can't _guarantee_ that a compiler even uses a parse tree :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Then you are actually guessing too. If you could not know that the compiler is using parse tree or that parentheses do not exist on the target platform or that the compiler optimizes them away, then you could not know parentheses have no runtime cost. I don't think there is anything about performance of extra parentheses in the standard, is it?

Comment: @JurajBlaho, that's why I said "shouldn't" rather than "won't". You should also note the smiley at the end of my previous comment. I don't doubt Cornstalks is right on that point. And you're dead right, while there is the odd mention of complexity requirements, the C and C++ standards for runtime behaviour, they don't tend to concentrate on performance of the compilation process itself.

Answer (score 6):

No, and I'll walk through the typical compiler phases and show you why they don't.

The first phase of compiling is lexing, turning characters (or sequences of them) into tokens. The expression `((x*y)+(((z*c))))` might be tokenized like:

```
LEFT_PAREN
LEFT_PAREN
ID x
SYMBOL *
ID y
RIGHT_PAREN
SYMBOL +
LEFT_PAREN
LEFT_PAREN
LEFT_PAREN
ID z
SYMBOL *
ID c
RIGHT_PAREN
RIGHT_PAREN
RIGHT_PAREN
RIGHT_PAREN
RIGHT_PAREN
```

After this, the parser comes along and builds a parse tree (and throws away things it no longer needs, like parentheses). The parse tree might look like this:

```
      +
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  *       *
 / \     / \
X   Y   Z   C
```

The parentheses no longer exist at this point, so no, they won't impact the rest of the compiling phase (including the code generation). The order of evaluation of the expression (the whole point of adding parentheses) is implicitly encoded in the structure of the tree itself, so the parentheses no longer have a purpose and are thrown away. Sure, during the lexing and parsing they'll have to be processed, adding some nanoseconds to your compile time, but that's about it. They don't exist beyond that, and thus won't impact execution time.